# Golang: How to UTF8 both subject header and body in email?

Tags: email, go, utf-8

I'm interested in how to pass string (successfully - in UTF8) containing both subject header and body of email to this function:

```
func sendEmail(body string) {
    c, err := smtp.Dial(".....")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer c.Close()
    // Set the sender and recipient.
    c.Mail(".....")
    c.Rcpt(".....")

    // Send the email body.
    wc, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer wc.Close()

    buf := bytes.NewBufferString(body)
    if _, err = buf.WriteTo(wc); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

And then I've got here subject header and email body;

```
body := "Subject: Header string which contains ŽČĆŠĐ in name of user " + name + "!\n" 
body += "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" 
body += "String inside email body which also might contain ŽČĆŠĐ" + year_month_day_hour_minute + " - " + end_of_shift

//function call
sendEmail(body)
```

I've thought it should run ok ...and it really does display correctly subject header string (in utf8) but for some unknown reason the rest of email body gets displayed in junk form.

[image: email body text junk format]

I've tried to change a few minor details but nothing really changed in principle.

This is my first Go example so I could easily overlook obvious.

Thanks for any thoughts on the matter!

Comment: You use `body` for headers. This is wrong. Headers have own convention to quote non-ASCII characters, so either you encode such things, or look at your library, on how to add Subject and generic headers.

Comment: Data() can be used both for header and body.  ```https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/``` and see "func (*Client) Data"

Comment: Yeah, then I saw the package. Unfortunately the package is about SMTP, and not email (two different standards, but published in parallel, one next to the other). I didn't see any packages about email (so encoding of headers, and formatting header correctly, email standard date format, body encoding, etc.), so you may want to look to an external library. In short: header should be ASCII + a sort of escaping: MIME "encoded-word". Recently mail could negotiate UTF8 headers, with extension: `SMTPUTF8`

Answer (score 3):

try:
In your text subject use this function

```
func cSubject(subject string) string {
    //return "=?iso-8859-1?Q?" + subject + "?="
    return "=?utf-8?q?" + subject + "?="
}
```

Comment: answer was right and confirmed by reading this page https://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/

Answer (score 2):

Hi I successfully sent UTF8 email using golang with the following code

```
func sendContactUs(name string, email string, userInput string) {
    // Sender data.
    from := "some@email.address"
    password := "some password"

    // Receiver email address.
    to := []string{
        "receipient@email.address",
    }

    // smtp server configuration.
    smtpHost := "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpPort := "587"

    raw := `Subject: {name} Contact form on Web
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"


    Dear Manager,

    We receive a a form submission from webpage
    name  : {name}    
    email : {email}
    message:

    {message}

    Kind Regards
    XXXX  Mailing service team.
`

    raw = strings.Replace(raw, "{name}", name, -1)
    raw = strings.Replace(raw, "{email}", email, -1)
    raw = strings.Replace(raw, "{message}", userInput, -1)

    // Message.
    message := []byte(raw)

    // Authentication.
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", from, password, smtpHost)

    // Sending email.
    err := smtp.SendMail(smtpHost+":"+smtpPort, auth, from, to, message)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Email Sent Successfully!")
}
```

Please note the line with **Content-type:** it must start at the very beginning.
In other words, it should not have any prepending blank space.

Also, it must have a blank line after it.

It's a working code. please try it out.  If you encounter any problems please let me know.